# Display a custom field with Rendered in Product Grid UI Component in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to add one custom field in Product Grid UI Component where It will display some text which will fetch from Product Custom Option.

I tried lots of solution but all are for other Grid system not the Magento 2 Product Grid UI Component. I found how to add an custom image but I want to display one of my Custom Option in the Product Grid UI Component.